# convert javascript Associative Array to multi object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is my input:

where input may receive more data like `'e:5'`

```
  var input = {a:2,b:3,c:2,d:1};
```

I want to convert this input into below output:

```
var output = [{name="a",id="2"},
              {name="b",id="3"},
              {name="c",id="2"},
              {name="d",id="1"}];
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

---

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

---

```js
var input = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 2,
  d: 1
};

var mapped = Object.keys(input).map(function(key) {
  return {
    name: key,
    id: input[key]
  };
});
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var input = {a:2,b:3,c:2,d:1};
var output = [];
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key){
  output.push({name:key,id:input[key]});
  })
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object properties are unordered. Because of that, the order of keys returned from [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is undetermined. In order to maintain the alphabetical order like your example, you need to previously [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys , then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the expected value.

I don't like ES5. So here is my ES6 answer.

```
Object.keys(input).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).map(name => ({name, id: input[name]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for some fun and for training purposes we may come up with this. Remember that while it's possible to add later, you can always embed a Symbol.iterator method by the constructor function at the time of instantiation and your objects become iterable by default.

```js
var input = {a:2,b:3,c:2,d:1},
   output = [];
input[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
                           var ok = Object.keys(this),
                                i = 0;
                           while (i < ok.length) yield {[ok[i]]: this[ok[i++]]};
                         };
for (var keyValuePair of input) output.push(keyValuePair);
console.log(output);

// or you can even do like
output.length = 0;
output = [...input]; // cool
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below approach :

```
var input = {a:2,b:3,c:2,d:1};

var output = Object.keys(input).reduce(function(p, c){
     return p.concat({name:c, id:input[c]});
}, []);
```